# In C++, how do I obtain an output exactly like a calculator?

Tags: c++

I use setprecision & fixed, but I want to cut off trailing zeros, how do I do that for cout?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>

int main()
{
    double b = 132.7489;
    double a = 49.932;
    double e = a + b;
    std::cout << std::fixed;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(20);
    std::cout << e;
}
```

How do I tell the program to automatically cut off the trailing decimal places for the exact answer like a calculator. Sorry this is my first time here. I'm used to Javascript & I've never had a problem with exact math. I've googled everywhere.

Comment: show the code ,so we can know what exactly you did....

Comment: Any reason why something like this wouldn't work? `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << 4.32523626;
`

Comment: If the number was 4.3000000, your solution would give him 4.300. He wants 4.3

Answer (score 2):

This will do it...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    float f = 42.43500000f, f2 = 25.004300;
    cout << defaultfloat << f << endl;
    cout << defaultfloat << f2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[`defaultfloat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/defaultfloat/) is a format flag defined in the std namespace.

Comment: I'm using GNU GCC compiler, I see in the documentation of this that it needs to be c++ 2011 standard or more. I'm using code:blocks IDE. I keep getting error. Something about not declaring it in the scope. Are you using MSCV?

Answer (score 0):

If printing is your only concern you could use `printf` and `%g` format.

As by default six significant digits are printed ,you could use long enough numeric width like `.10`.

```
printf("%.10g",e);
```

So:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdio>
int main()
{
    double b = 132.7489;
    double a = 49.932;
    double e = a + b;
    printf("%.10g",e);
}
```

Comment: If I were to change a & b's value like 42.49887298340827342623974, %.10g doesn't actually display longer decimal places. I need automatic accuracy like a calculator. Not something I'd have to change %g format all the time.

Comment: @JohnLalani First of all double could only take max 15 digits so either change data type   if you want such high precision and second you dont need to change `%g` format everytime just add large enough numeric width depending upon how high you want precision like `%.15g`. As calculator too have their precision limits. So you can set yourself any precision limit and add it to `%g` format.

Comment: Oh ok, so I need a high precision data type, thank you!